# With two balls connected to a string find minimum upward velocity that can be given to one of the balls such that the other leaves the ground

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, momentum, energy-conservation

The exact question is given below:

> Two identical small balls A and B each of mass m connected by a light inextensible cord of length l are placed on a frictionless horizontal floor. With what velocity u must the ball B be projected vertically upwards so that the ball A leaves the floor? Acceleration of free fall is g.
>   [image]
>   $$Answer: u \ge \sqrt{3gl} $$

I found this question in a book that is focused towards olympiads and was not able to figure it out. Now, even after many attempts have not been able to arrive at the answer in a completely satisfactory manner. I am looking for a satisfactory explanation and solution to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider the final state when $B$ is directly above $A$ which is still touching the ground. In order to lift up $A$, the tension in the string must be greater than the weight of $A$.
$$T\ge mg$$
But since ball $B$ will be in circular motion around $A$, the tension is equal to the centripetal force.
$$\frac {mv^2}l\ge mg$$
$$v\ge \sqrt {gl}$$
Finally, equating initial kinetic energy and final kinetic and potential energy. 
$$\frac 12mu^2=\frac 12 mv^2+mgl$$
$$u^2=v^2+2gl$$
$$u^2\ge gl+2gl$$
$$u\ge \sqrt {3gl}$$

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why B will be in circular motion around A at the highest point? Also, how can we be sure that the ball A will only lift up at the point when B is directly above A?

Comment: $B$ will always be in circular motion around $A$ because it was imparted velocity perpendicular to the radius vector. Ball $A$ can be lifted up earlier but the tension is maximum at the topmost point and hence at that point, velocity required will be minimum.

Comment: @AjayMohan Your concepts seem to be all over the place. The upward force experienced by $A$ is a function of $\sin \theta$ which is maximum at the top. Nowhere have I considered a non-inertial reference frame, all equations are with respect to ground.

Comment: @Sam I'm sorry for being unclear. I have two points to make: (1) Tension force is not constant. It too depends on $\theta$: $T=T (\theta) $. (2) In the ground frame, wouldn't you agree that A experiences acceleration due to the horizontal component of tension ($T \cos \theta) $?

Comment: @Sam i have a doubt if you could please clear it.
In the given question won't A also have a horizontal velocity due to tension.
I think that horizontal component of B's velocity and A's velocity must be equal as same force(Tcos(angle)) is acting on both of them.
So at the point where B is just above A both will have same velocity v.
Hence in energy conservation (mv^2)/2 will be replaced by mv^2.
If I did some mistake pls correct me.

Comment: @AjayMohan As per the question, we are uninterested in the dynamics of A in the horizontal axis. However, it is true that ball A will have motion in the $+\hat{x}$ direction too during this process.

Comment: @saumy The magnitude of horizontal component is the same for A and B but in the opposite directions. At no point will both the balls have equal velocity.

Answer (score 0):

As @saumy points out, both A and B see equal and opposite horizontal forces and therefore the horizontal velocities are equal and opposite at all times. When B is directly above A, both bodies are instantaneously *rotating around the mid-point of the string*.  The tension in the string due to the rotation is $mv^2/(L/2)$. When this force is greater than the weight of A, then A will lift off the table:
$$mv^2/(L/2) >= mg$$
Now equating the initial kinetic energy with the final kinetic + potential energy:
$$m_Bu^2/2 = m_Av^2/2 + m_Bv^2/2 + m_BgL$$
Finally setting $m=m_A=m_B$ and eliminating $v^2$, we get the limiting initial velocity:
$$u >= \sqrt{3gL}$$
That this is the same answer is probably not a coincidence.  However, it's not entirely clear to me what justifies saying this condition occurs when B is vertically above A. The rotation is faster and the tension in the string is higher just before it reaches this point. But I don't know whether the   vertical component of the tension is higher.